# React Native Android Release build crashing at startup

Tags: android, react-native, crash, release

I have build my release build with gradlew assembleRelease and when launching the app it is crashing with the following stacktrace

```
07-05 12:41:27.318  6703  6703 I com.package: Using CollectorTypeCC GC.
07-05 12:41:27.331  6703  6703 E com.package: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
07-05 12:41:27.381  6703  6703 D nativeloader: Configuring clns-6 for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.package
07-05 12:41:27.386  6703  6703 D nativeloader: Configuring clns-7 for other apk /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.package
07-05 12:41:27.405  6703  6703 V GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE GameManagerService for com.package: false
07-05 12:41:27.405  6703  6703 V GraphicsEnvironment: com.package is not listed in per-application setting
07-05 12:41:27.418  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64
07-05 12:41:27.419  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64
07-05 12:41:27.419  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-05 12:41:27.420  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libandroid.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64
07-05 12:41:27.420  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libandroid.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-05 12:41:27.420  6703  6703 V SoLoader: liblog.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64
07-05 12:41:27.420  6703  6703 V SoLoader: liblog.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-05 12:41:27.420  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libm.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64
07-05 12:41:27.420  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libm.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-05 12:41:27.421  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64
07-05 12:41:27.421  6703  6703 V SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-05 12:41:27.425  6703  6703 D SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-05 12:41:27.438  6703  6732 V SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64
07-05 12:41:27.439   533  1116 D CoreBackPreview: Window{290c75 u0 com.package/com.package.MainActivity}: Setting back callback OnBackInvokedCallbackInfo{mCallback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@e50e298, mPriority=0, mIsAnimationCallback=false}
07-05 12:41:27.440  6703  6732 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-05 12:41:27.440  6703  6732 V SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/lib/arm64
07-05 12:41:27.442  6703  6732 D SoLoader: libfbjni.so found on /data/app/~~N1YncuPGh_zrhQI5CvpCrg==/com.package-qzX3GGTr_m3k0vQ3sJC7mg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-05 12:41:27.453  6703  6732 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.package, PID: 6703
07-05 12:41:27.456   533  1116 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.package/com.package.MainActivity
07-05 12:41:27.465   533  2111 I ActivityManager: Process com.package (pid 6703) has died: fg  TOP 
07-05 12:41:27.465   533  1663 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{290c75 u0 com.package/com.package.MainActivity}
07-05 12:41:27.465   533  1663 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object '290c75 com.package/com.package.MainActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
07-05 12:41:27.507   533   554 V WindowManager:     info={id=42 t=CLOSE f=0x10 trk=0 r=[0@Point(0, 0)] c=[{WCT{RemoteToken{8904098 Task{70f29ba #1 type=home}}} m=SHOW f=SHOW_WALLPAPER leash=Surface(name=Task=1)/@0x4e53aa0 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 1024) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 1024) d=0},{WCT{RemoteToken{f001413 Task{7ba177f #28 type=standard A=10185:com.package}}} m=CLOSE f=NONE leash=Surface(name=Task=28)/@0x357777 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 1024) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 1024) d=0}]}
07-05 12:41:27.534   533  2138 D CoreBackPreview: Window{fdb08aa u0 Splash Screen com.package EXITING}: Setting back callback null
07-05 12:41:27.534   533  2073 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'fdb08aa Splash Screen com.package (c@lient)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
```

Here is my config:
Mac Book Pro M2

React Native 0.70.8

Also when submitting the app on the store, my pre launch report says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=> Make sure you have run this command before the making release for entry file for android & ios.

Android :-

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

Ios:-

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'
```

Comment: I don't even see the assets folder

Comment: so make it first.

Comment: but how do I create the file ?

Comment: go to the android/app/src/main folder and run ```mkdir assets``` command.

Comment: I don't have the index.android.js either it seems

Comment: Ok i used the index.js

Comment: Seems to be working.. It's odd because I've never had to do it before

Comment: @AlixHumbert can you please approve my answer so SC can relate this.

Comment: I'm facing this issue after upgrading an older app. Not sure if it helps, we also never had to do this in the past. Maybe this became necessary at some point due to updates/upgrades..?

Comment: Okay I can confirm that indeed this helps. 
Included the bundle command in my publishing script just before the regular fastlane build that used to be enough in the past.

Comment: Be really really super careful to only use the version of the AGP (gradle plugin) compatible with the version of RN you are using. Use react native upgrade helper online tool to get the right plugin version